# How to use Sphinx's autodoc to document a class's __init__(self) method?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

Sphinx doesn't generate docs for __init__(self) by default. I have tried the following:

```
.. automodule:: mymodule
    :members:
```

and

```
..autoclass:: MyClass
    :members:
```

In conf.py, setting the following only appends the __init__(self) docstring to the class docstring ([the Sphinx autodoc documentation](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/autodoc.html) seems to agree that this is the expected behavior, but mentions nothing regarding the problem I'm trying to solve):

```
autoclass_content = 'both'
```

Comment: No, that is not what the documentation writes as of today, at least: `"both"
    Both the class’ and the __init__ method’s docstring are concatenated and inserted.` -> Therefore, it ought not to be only the `__init__(self)`, but also the class docstring if you have that. Can you provide a test case because if it is so, it feels like a bug, right?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Here are three alternatives:

1. To ensure that `__init__()` is always documented, you can use [`autodoc-skip-member`](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/autodoc.html#skipping-members) in conf.py. Like this:

   ```
   def skip(app, what, name, obj, would_skip, options):
       if name == "__init__":
           return False
       return would_skip

   def setup(app):
       app.connect("autodoc-skip-member", skip)
   ```

   This explicitly defines `__init__` not to be skipped (which it is by default). This configuration is specified once, and it does not require any additional markup for every class in the .rst source.
2. The [`special-members`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html) option was [added in Sphinx 1.1](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/changes.html#release-1-1-oct-9-2011). It makes "special" members (those with names like `__special__`) be documented by autodoc.

   Since Sphinx 1.2, this option takes arguments which makes it more useful than it was previously.
3. Use `automethod`:

   ```
   .. autoclass:: MyClass     
      :members: 

      .. automethod:: __init__
   ```

   This has to be added for every class (cannot be used with `automodule`, as pointed out in a comment to the first revision of this answer).

Comment: That doesn't help with automodule since it has to be added to every class.

Comment: The first alternative worked. In my case it was better than the second and third alternatives, as it doesn't need to be editing .rst files.

Comment: In Sphinx 1.2.1, `special-members` works fine using `automodule`. Use `:special-members: __init__` to document only `__init__`.

Comment: None of these alternatives worked for me in Sphinx 5.3.0

Answer (score 95):

You were close. You can use the [`autoclass_content`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html#confval-autoclass_content) option in your `conf.py` file:

```
autoclass_content = 'both'
```

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: I am wondering about that, too... Did you understand the high upvote rate of this answer? At first, it looks like an answer that should be purged.

Comment: I tried setting the `autoclass_content = 'both'` option, which did document the __init__ method, but it made the autosummary appear twice.

Comment: This is the best way to do it, it works perfectly with autosummary and the result it's much better than `special-methods`, the former add the constructor doc right at the start of the class and the latter adds a separate `__init__` method to the doc.

Answer (score 15):

Even though this is an older post, for those who are looking it up as of now, there is also another solution introduced in version 1.8. According to the [documentation](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_default_options), You can add the  `special-members` key in the `autodoc_default_options` to your `conf.py`.

Example:

```
autodoc_default_options = {
    'members': True,
    'member-order': 'bysource',
    'special-members': '__init__',
    'undoc-members': True,
    'exclude-members': '__weakref__'
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Over the past years I've written several variants of `autodoc-skip-member` callbacks for various unrelated Python projects because I wanted methods like `__init__()`, `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` to show up in my API documentation (after all, these "special methods" are part of the API and what better place to document them than inside the special method's docstring).

Recently I took the best implementation and made it part of one of my Python projects ([here's the documentation](https://humanfriendly.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#humanfriendly.sphinx.enable_special_methods)). [The implementation](https://github.com/xolox/python-humanfriendly/blob/master/humanfriendly/sphinx.py) basically comes down to this:

```
import types

def setup(app):
    """Enable Sphinx customizations."""
    enable_special_methods(app)


def enable_special_methods(app):
    """
    Enable documenting "special methods" using the autodoc_ extension.

    :param app: The Sphinx application object.

    This function connects the :func:`special_methods_callback()` function to
    ``autodoc-skip-member`` events.

    .. _autodoc: http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html
    """
    app.connect('autodoc-skip-member', special_methods_callback)


def special_methods_callback(app, what, name, obj, skip, options):
    """
    Enable documenting "special methods" using the autodoc_ extension.

    Refer to :func:`enable_special_methods()` to enable the use of this
    function (you probably don't want to call
    :func:`special_methods_callback()` directly).

    This function implements a callback for ``autodoc-skip-member`` events to
    include documented "special methods" (method names with two leading and two
    trailing underscores) in your documentation. The result is similar to the
    use of the ``special-members`` flag with one big difference: Special
    methods are included but other types of members are ignored. This means
    that attributes like ``__weakref__`` will always be ignored (this was my
    main annoyance with the ``special-members`` flag).

    The parameters expected by this function are those defined for Sphinx event
    callback functions (i.e. I'm not going to document them here :-).
    """
    if getattr(obj, '__doc__', None) and isinstance(obj, (types.FunctionType, types.MethodType)):
        return False
    else:
        return skip
```

Yes, there's more documentation than logic :-). The advantage of defining an `autodoc-skip-member` callback like this over the use of the `special-members` option (for me) is that the `special-members` option also enables documentation of properties like `__weakref__` (available on all new-style classes, AFAIK) which I consider noise and not useful at all. The callback approach avoids this (because it only works on functions/methods and ignores other attributes).

Comment: How do I use this? It seems the method must be named `setup(app)` in order to be executed by Sphinx.

Comment: I don't understand it all, but see xolox's [implementation](https://github.com/xolox/python-humanfriendly/blob/master/humanfriendly/sphinx.py) if you want to dissect yourself. I believe he built a sphinx extension that connects a callback to the autodoc-skip-member event.  When sphinx tries to figure out if something should be included/skipped that event fires, and his code runs.  If his code detects a __special__ member that was defined explicitly by the user (inherited like often happens) then it tells Sphinx to include it.  That way you can doc special members you write yourself

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications Andrew and yes you are correct oarfish, a setup function is needed. I've added it to the example to avoid further confusion.

Comment: @JoelB: The example code in my post is written to assume that your `__init__` method has a nonempty docstring. Does it?

Answer (score 1):

As long as this commit approved: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/pull/9154, in the next sphinx version (>4.1.2) will be possible to:

```
..autoclass:: MyClass1
    :members:
    :class-doc-from: class


..autoclass:: MyClass2
    :members:
    :class-doc-from: init
```

Comment: the correct syntax to do this would be to remove the quotes around so it's like:
`:class-doc-from: class`

Answer (score 0):

This is a variant which only includes `__init__` if it has arguments:

```
import inspect

def skip_init_without_args(app, what, name, obj, would_skip, options):
    if name == '__init__':
        func = getattr(obj, '__init__')
        spec = inspect.getfullargspec(func)
        return not spec.args and not spec.varargs and not spec.varkw and not spec.kwonlyargs
    return would_skip

def setup(app):
    app.connect("autodoc-skip-member", skip_init_without_args)
```

Comment: did not work for me