# Autodoc an __init__(self) method: getting "autodoc-skip-member" to work

Tags: python-sphinx, autodoc

There is a previous question on getting Sphinx to document certain special methods only (the `__init__(self)` in that case): [How to use Sphinx's autodoc to document a class's __init__(self) method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599254/how-to-use-sphinxs-autodoc-to-document-a-classs-init-self-method/5599712#5599712)

The accepted answer lists 3 options, the first of which is to use a custom function to handle the "autodoc-skip-member" event. The answer suggests adding this code to `conf.py`:

```
def skip(app, what, name, obj, skip, options):
    if name == "__init__":
        return False
    return skip

def setup(app):
    app.connect("autodoc-skip-member", skip)
```

This would really work great in my case, since it is global, i.e. requires no editing of *.rst files. The problem is, I cannot get it to work. I added the code to `conf.py`, however, the `__init__()` method does not show up in the docs. I can use

```
autodoc_default_flags = ['special-members']
```

to include all special methods, but I was really hoping to have more control and include just some of them (`__init__()` and possibly `__repr__()`). Does this approach work for other people? Is there anything else I need to do to get it to work?

Thanks,
Aleksey

Comment: Are you by any chance also using napoleon? I have a similar symptom in that scenario. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36270358/sphinx-autodoc-skip-member-handler-cant-show-init-when-using-napoleon

Answer (score 0):

Per https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/2374, where the conflict is with Napoleon, if you're using any extensions that also sets a handler for the "autodoc-skip-member" event only one of the handlers will be used. Could this be the issue you encountered?