# sphinx autodoc-skip-member handler: can't show __init__() when using napoleon

Tags: python, python-sphinx, sphinx-napoleon

I want to include the docstrings for `__init__()` in my sphinx-generated documentation.

I was following [the accepted answer to this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599254/how-to-use-sphinxs-autodoc-to-document-a-classs-init-self-method) to add a handler for `autodoc-skip-member` and was still unable to see my `__init__()` documentation. Trace code inside the `if name == "__init__":` block shows I am hitting that code.

On a hunch I removed `'sphinx.ext.napoleon'` from my `extensions` definition, leaving

```
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    # 'sphinx.ext.napoleon',
]
```

and then I can see the `__init__()` documentation.

The only thing I see in [the napoleon documentation](http://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.org/en/latest/sphinxcontrib.napoleon.html) that seems relevant is `napoleon_include_special_with_doc`, which it says defaults to `True`. Explicitly setting it to `True` in `conf.py` doesn't seem to change anything.

ETA: If I add the following method:

```
def __blah__(self):
    '''blah blah blah'''
    print self.__class__
```

I see `__blah__()` in my generated documentation.

- If I change the name of `__blah__` to `__repr__` or `__str__`,
  I see them in the generated documentation.
- If I comment out the existing `__init__` and change
  `__blah__` to `__init__` I don't see it.

So it seems specific to `__init__()`.

Is this a known issue, and is there another way to control this when using napoleon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Rob's followon at https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/2374, if you're using any extension that also sets a handler for the "autodoc-skip-member" event only one of the handlers will be used. This would seem to be the issue at hand. Thanks Rob!

Answer (score 0):

Napoleon defers to your autodoc configuration for how you want to handle the `__init__` method.

Check your autodoc settings in `conf.py`. In particular, make sure [autoclass_content](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html#confval-autoclass_content) is set to either `init` or `both`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Rob.

I'm pretty sure autoclass_content isn't the difference.

What I was trying to do is put the class documentation under the class, and then have __init__() appear as a method just like __repr__() or __str__() or any other method, with its own documentation.

autoclass_content = 'both' just adds the __init__() documentation to the class documentation without calling out __init__() as a separate function.

autoclass_content = 'init' uses the __init__() documentation as the entirety of the class documentation, and also omits __init__() as a separate function.